# C++ primer 5 edition: count reference and underlying pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

In C++ primer 5 Edition. Chapter 12 `std::shared_ptr` it is said that:

```
p = q;
```

"`p` and `q` are `shared_ptr`s holding pointers that can be converted to one another. Decrements `p`'s reference count and increments `q`'s count, deletes `p`'s existing memory if `p`'s count goes to 0."

So I've tried this:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sp1 = std::make_shared<int>(10);
decltype(sp1) sp2 = nullptr;

std::cout << sp1.use_count() << std::endl;
std::cout << sp2.use_count() << std::endl;

sp2 = sp1;

std::cout << sp1.use_count() << std::endl;
std::cout << sp2.use_count() << std::endl;
```

The output:

```
sp1.use_count(): 1
sp2.use_count(): 0
sp1.use_count(): 2
sp2.use_count(): 2
```

- Why `sp1` and `sp2` has the same `use_count`? And it is said above that that assignment decrements `p`'s reference count and increments `q`'s count??
- Also I didn't know which case can be the underlying pointers in `sp1` and `sp2` convertible to each other other than being the same type:

  ```
  std::shared_ptr<int> spi = std::make_shared<int>(0);
  std::shared_ptr<short> sps = spi; // error
  ```

I think `short` can be converted to `int` but why it doesn't work? As I may know it is similar to container: The containers types (type name and element type) must be the same. Then I don't understand that point here in the book: "`p` and `q` are `shared_ptr`s holding pointers that can be converted to one another."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why sp1 and sp2 has the same use_count?

You have two shared pointers, `sp1` and `sp2`, pointing to the same resource.

So, both shared pointers indicate that the "use count" of the resource is 2.

---

> it is said above that that assignment decrements p's reference count and increments q's count??

It would do if `p` was originally pointing to something else. You'd now have one fewer shared pointer that points to that other resource.

---

> I think [`int`] can be converted to [`short`] but why it doesn't work?

Yes, an `int` can be converted to a `short`. That is, you can take an `int` and create a new `short` that holds the same value (if it's within the range of the type).

But a `short` is not an `int`, so if you have an `int`, you cannot use a `short*` to point to it.

That's regardless of shared pointers. Just try:

```
int x = 0;
short* y = &x;
```

and you'll see that you can't have this, nor does it make sense to.

---

> As I may know it is similar to container: The containers types (type name and element type) must be the same

No, it doesn't have much to do with that.

---

> I don't understand that point here in the book: "p and q are shared_ptrs holding pointers that can be converted to one another."

Some pointers *are* convertible, such as `Derived*` to `Base*`.

He means, "in this example, assume that `p` and `q` are both `shared_ptr`s, either of the exact same type, or at least of convertible type, so that the `=` is legal".

Comment: Thank you for this good explanation. "holding pointers that can be converted to one another"? I don't know what his meaning? Does he mean the values in pointers can be converted to each other or the pointers themselves?? Thank you.

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa Some pointers _are_ convertible, such as `Derived*` to `Base*`. He means, "assume that `p` and `q` are both shared_ptrs, either the exact same type, or at least of convertible type, so that the `=` is legal"

Comment: It is above in the question: "p = q;

"p and q are shared_ptrs holding pointers that can be converted to one another."

Comment: AAAh! Yes. Thank you very much. I really missed it. Inheritance.

Comment: No problem Itachi

Comment: You are really amazing. Thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

> Why `sp1` and `sp2` has the same `use_count()`? And it is said above that that
>   assignment decrements `p`'s reference count and increments `q`'s count??

What the book means with:

> Decrements `p`'s reference count and
>   increments `q`'s count, deletes `p`'s existing memory if `p`'s count goes to
>   `0`.

Is that if `p` is already pointing to something then that count will be decremented before `p` will be pointing to the same thing as `q`.

---

If instead of this code:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sp1 = std::make_shared<int>(10);
decltype(sp1) sp2 = nullptr;
```

You had this code:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sp1 = std::make_shared<int>(10); // use_count() == 1
decltype(sp1) sp2 = std::make_shared<int>(5); // // use_count() == 1
```

Then you'd see the moment you'd do `sp2 = sp1;` that `sp2`'s `use_count()` would first drop to 0 and thus deleting the memory that holds the integer `5`, and then starts pointing at the memory that holds the integer `10`, to which `use_count()` is now `2` because both `sp1` and `sp2` are now pointing to it.

Comment: Really good and easy to understand. Thank you. Please add the second part.